# コマンドの標準出力をファイルにリダイレクトしたいが、コマンド実行後に入力を求められる場合の対処法

Tags: linux, bash

以下のようにあるコマンドを実行した際に、その出力をファイルに書き出したいと考えています。
ただ、コマンド実行後に入力を求められ、入力が完了しないと次の処理に進まないような挙動をしています。
このような場合、どう対処すればいいでしょうか。
ご教授お願い致します。

例）

```bash
$ command > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`command <<< hoge > output.txt` のように`<<<`で1行の入力を受け取る方法や、
`echo hoge | command > output.txt` のようにパイプで渡す方法でできます。

複数回の入力が必要な場合は、ヒアドキュメント `<< 終端文字` で複数のコマンドを渡すことができます。

**サンプルスクリプト**(read_sample.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Press any key: " DATA
echo "Entered key: $DATA" 
if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = "-two_inputs" ]; then
    read -p "Press next key: " DATA
    echo "next key: $DATA" 
fi
```

**コマンド**

```
$ ./read_sample.sh <<< hoge > output.txt
$ ./read_sample.sh -two_inputs << \\e >> output.txt
fuga
piyo
\e
```

**実行結果**(output.txt)

```
Entered key: hoge
Entered key: fuga
next key: piyo
```

**参考資料**

- [覚えてると案外便利なBashのリダイレクト・パイプの使い方9個](https://orebibou.com/ja/home/201602/20160229_001/)
- [UNIX & Linux コマンド・シェルスクリプト リファレンス](https://shellscript.sunone.me/input_output.html#%E3%83%92%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88-)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。とても参考になりました。無事疑問が解決いたしました。